# Asymptotics of ratios of polynomially recursive sequences

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, recurrences

A sequence $a_n$ is said to be *polynomially recursive (P-recursive)* if it satisfies:

$$p^{[r]}(n)a_{n+r}+\cdots+p^{[1]}(n)a_{n+1}+\cdots + p^{[0]}(n)a_n=0$$

where $p^{[i]}(t)\in \mathbb{Q}[t]$ are polynomials with rational coefficients, with $p^{[0]},p^{[r]}$ not identically zero.

For example, $a_n:=n!$ is one such sequence since: $2a_{n+2}-(n+2)a_{n+1}-(n+1)(n+2)a_n=0$, with initial conditions $a_0:=0, a_1:=1$.

Fix a set of polynomials $\{p^{[i]}(t)\}_{i=0}^r$, and suppose $a_n,b_n$ are a pair of sequences that satisfy the **same** above recurrence, with **different initial conditions**. Furthermore, suppose that both sequences aren’t ultimately periodic or constant.

Define $L :=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$.

> **Main Question**:  Is it obvious when $L\in (0,\infty)$? In other words, when does $L$ exist, is non-zero and non-infinite? Aside from numerically evaluating the limit for large enough $n$, are there any algorithmic methods for deducing that $L \in (0,\infty)$?

There are many known (non-trivial) results about the growth rates of such sequences, for example results due to Poincaré, Birkhoff and Trjitzinsky, [Wimp and Zeilberger](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82062113.pdf), and [Mezzarobba and Salvy](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.2452). However, I'm unable to find good references related to my question, especially as a function of initial conditions. The main difficulty I have is that I’m not sure how to find good lower bounds on the growth rates of such sequences.

Comment: You probably assume $p^{[r]},p^{[0]}\neq 0$.

Comment: I am really not familiar with this topic, but I took a look at your reference by Mezzarobba and Salvy. Their method seems to use the initial values only for the computation of the constant factor of the upper bound, and they said that their bound is generically tight (I don't know what it means). Doesn't these two facts imply that your main question holds at least generically?

Comment: @YCor: yes. Technically if $p^{[0]}(n)$ has positive integer zeros, then we need additional initial conditions to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: @Hhan: thanks for your observation. I’m still trying to make sense of that paper but part of the issue seems that they only have an upper bound so I’m not sure if that would be enough to conclude what happens to my ratio.

Comment: I took a more closer look at the paper. Theorem 2 (a) in the paper may say your question holds in many case (some complex condition wrt Newton polygon). More generic case, (I does not figure out the exact meaning) the tightness of the paper's upper bound doesn't seem to fit in your question (See Proposition 10 for their tightness; it only says about limsup). But it could give a hint for counter example of your question.

Comment: I mean, the initial condition that only satisfies such weak tightness could be a counter example of your question. I am not sure such condition and P-recursive sequnce exist. I guess it may be discussed in a reference.

Comment: Even as simple an example with degree-$0$ polynomials such as $a_{n+2}-5a_{n+1}-6a_n=0$ has both $2^n$ and $3^n$ among the sequences satisfying it. I believe in such case the irreducibility of the associated  polynomial $x^2-5x-6$ is all that's missing to guarantee that $L$ is finite. But I doubt anything nearly as simple would hold in higher degrees.

Comment: I assume your sequences are integral or rational.

Comment: Note that $L$ need not exist, even for constant coefficients when the associated (characteristic) polynomial is irreducible, e.g., $a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}+a_n=0$, with initial conditions $a_0=1, a_1=-1$ and $a_0=0, a_1=1$.

Comment: @Richard Stanley: Right, this is actually a crux of my question, because I’d like the limit to exist and it’s not obvious to me when it even does.

Comment: @Yaakov Baruch: Right, the polynomials are rational (and can be assumed as integral wlog).

Comment: I was asking if the sequences are rational.

Comment: @Yaakov Baruch: oh, in that case sure, let’s assume the initial conditions are rational.

Comment: I guess $b_n$ are required to be non-zero.

Answer (score 3):

This is a difficult question in general; see for instance

- [https://people.mpi-sws.org/~joel/publications/positivity_and_minimality_holonomic21abs.html](https://people.mpi-sws.org/%7Ejoel/publications/positivity_and_minimality_holonomic21abs.html)
- [https://people.mpi-sws.org/~joel/publications/holonomic-second-order21abs.html](https://people.mpi-sws.org/%7Ejoel/publications/holonomic-second-order21abs.html)

for recent work on special cases. (As you noted, the paper by Bruno Salvy and myself that you mention is purely about upper bounds and thus not terribly relevant.)

However, there are sufficient conditions for $L$ to be nonzero and finite that can be verified algorithmically and cover a fair number of (“easy”) cases. In particular, by passing to the differential equation on the generating series, one may be able to get “asymptotic expansions with error bounds” of the form, say, $|a_n - α f(n)| ≤ g(n)$, $|b_n - β f(n)| ≤ h(n)$ where $f$, $g$, $h$ are explicit functions with $g, h = o(g)$ and $α$, $β$ are constants that can be bounded from both sides. For more details on this kind of ideas, see for example

- https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.08155
- https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03291372/